# Can't prompt user for input because of NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner, do-while

I made this test class to test a method that loops until a user inputs the correct yes/no answer. It's throwing me this NoSuchElementFound Exception where it says there's no new line. How do I fix this?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
at Test.isDangerousMethod(Test.java:15)
at Test.main(Test.java:4)



import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isDangerousMethod());
    }
    private static boolean isDangerousMethod() {
        String answer;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("Warning: The command you entered may alter ");
            System.out.print("the files in your working directory. ");
            System.out.print("Uncommitted changes may be lost. ");
            System.out.println("Are you sure you want to continue? (yes/no)");
            answer = in.nextLine();
        } while (!answer.equals("yes") && !answer.equals("no"));
        in.close();
        return !answer.equals("no");
    }
}
```

Comment: The program as you posted should not throw that exception. Can you post the exception stack trace?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
 at Test.isDangerousMethod(Test.java:15)
 at Test.main(Test.java:4)

Comment: @Limone_77 What happens when you try just `in.next()`?

Comment: just a standard noSuchElementFoundException, except without saying "No such Line"